# How can I grab multiple records from a MySQL query in Perl using array pointers?

Tags: mysql, perl

I can do this all as one function, but in trying to port it over to my packages of functions (library) I am missing something.

Here's what I want to do from my main Perl script

```
my @rows;
$result = Funx::dbcdata($myConnection, 
          "SELECT * FROM Inv where name like \"%DOG%\";", \@rows);
```

Then in my library package I am attempting this

```
sub dbcdata
{
    my ($connection, $command, $array) = @_;

    my $query = $connection->prepare($command);
    my $result = $query->execute();

    my $i =0;
    while(my $row = $query->fetchrow_arrayref() )
    {
    @{$array}[$i] = $row;
    $i++;
    }
    $query->finish;
    return $result;
}
```

I was hoping to get back pointers or references to each row (which was 4in this case) but am not.  Every element in @rows is the same:

> ARRAY(0x5577a0f77ec0) ARRAY(0x5577a0f77ec0) ARRAY(0x5577a0f77ec0)
>   ARRAY(0x5577a0f77ec0)

Nor do I know how to turn each one into the original separate row.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: There are no _pointers_ in Perl. Do you mean _references_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchrow_arrayref) for `fetchrow_arrayref`:

> Note that the same array reference is returned for each fetch, so don't store the reference and then use it after a later fetch. Also, the elements of the array are also reused for each row, so take care if you want to take a reference to an element.

Sounds like you want [fetchall_arrayref](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchall_arrayref):

> The fetchall_arrayref method can be used to fetch all the data to be returned from a prepared and executed statement handle. It returns a reference to an array that contains one reference per row.

After executing the statement, you can do something like

```
@{$array} = $query->fetchall_arrayref->@*;
```

instead of that ugly loop.

But [selectall_array](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#selectall_array) might be even better. Your whole function can be replaced by a call to it:

```
my @rows =
     $myConnection->selectall_array(q/SELECT * FROM Inv WHERE name LIKE '%DOG%'/);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.... here is how I read the reference that is passed back.  Please let me know if there's a more proper way to do so.  Thanks again.
`    my $arrsize = @rows; 
 for (my $x =0; $x < $arrsize; $x++)
 {
  my $insize = @{$rows[$x]};
  print "-------------\n";
     for(my $y = 0; $y < $insize; $y++)
     {
      print "$rows[$x][$y]\n";

     }

 }`

Comment: @PlasticProgrammer A [foreach](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops) loop is a lot more idiomatic and easier to read those C-style for loops. Combining a suffix-style loop with `join` is one handy approach: `say "----\n", join("\n", @{$_}) for @rows;`